# Intersection of the NullT and ImT

Tags: linear-algebra

$T:V→V$ ; prove that if $T*T = T ⇒ ImT ∩ NullT = 0v$ and $V = ImT ⊕ NullT$.

let $v∈V$.

$$T(T(v)) = T(v) ⇒ T(v) = v$$

⇒ $T$ is the identity transformation.

⇒ $DimNullT = 0 ⇒ ImT ∩ NullT = 0v ⇒ V = ImT ⊕ NullT$

Is the answer correct?

Also does an example exist where the $ImT ∩ NullT ≠ 0v$? Isn't the intersection empty by definition?

Comment: Maybe someone will help you, but they should first consider the fact that you've asked 18 questions and accepted none of them and in fact you have never even upvoted.

Comment: What do you ask is "the correct answer"? You have shown nothing but unproved things. You wrote $\;\dim\ker T=0\;$, which of course is false in the general case (but this doesn't matter that much: you can't write without a proof such a thing and seriously expect things will go smoothly in an university level exam), and from here you deduce false things. Take seriously into consideration Casteels' comment.

Comment: @Casteels the fact I did not upvote does not mean I don't appreciate the answers - they have helped me greatly, but I will of course take this into consideration and improve.

Comment: @Timbuc: the question is not for the general case but for the specific condition. I'd appreciate if you give an actual answer rather than vent your anger in the post.

Comment: It's funny as I am sitting with a student of the Hebrew University and we've just solved this question from an exam in the past years. Anyway, I'm venting no anger here, just making sure you understand that what you ask, "is this a correct answer" should be, at the end of first semester, clear to you that it can **not** be even an answer, leave alone a correct one. When you do stuff in mathematics you *have to prove it*, not just state it. Even your claim that it is for the specific condition **must** be proved...and still is wrong, anyway.

Comment: Ah, well if you weren't venting then these personal comments are obviously the result of good intentions, not intentional condescendence. But of course you're right after all, or I wouldn't have posted here. But don't help further please..

Comment: @ofeklevy Ok, I will fill your last request.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $T^2=T$.

Suppose $Im(T)\cap \ker (T)\ne\{0\}$. Take $x\in Im(T)\cap \ker (T)$, $x\ne 0$. Then there is $v$ such that $Tv=x$.
Now
$$
x=Tv=T^2v =T(x)=0,
$$
which is a contradiction.

By the dimension theorems we have
$$
\dim(Im(T) + \ker(T)) =\dim(Im(T) ) + \dim(\ker(T)) -\dim(Im(T)\cap \ker (T)) \\
= \dim(Im(T) ) + \dim(\ker(T)) = \dim (V)
$$
Thus, $\dim(Im(T) + \ker(T))$ is a subspace of $V$ with the same dimension of $V$,
hence $\dim(Im(T) + \ker(T))=V$. Since the intersection is empty,
it follows
$$
\dim(Im(T) \oplus \ker(T))=V.
$$

Comment: I understand my errors, thanks!

Comment: Question. In your solution you wrote that $x=T(v)=T^2(v)$. I assume you used the fact that $IM T=IM T^2$. but I do not understand why that imply that the same $v$ will map for $x$ through $T$ and $T^2$.

Comment: $T=T^2$ by assumption

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken above:
I will try by contradiction:

Suppose ImT ∩ NullT = x ≠ 0v.

We know T(T(v)) = T(v)

then T(T(v) - v) = 0v

By the assumption T(v) - v = x ≠ 0v

Also exists y∈V such that T(y) = x

Then T(T(y)) = T(x) = T(y) = 0v which is a contradiction. then ImT ∩ NullT = 0v

Then dimNullT = 0. If dimV = n then dimImT = n. It follows from here that V = ImT ⊕ NullT.

Sorry for the mess in the comments and feedback will be appreciated.

Thx,

Comment: There is no assumption to give you $T(v)-v=x$. Also $\dim \ker(T)=0$ does not follow from anything. Take $T=0$ for a counterexample.

Comment: If T(T(v)) = T(v) then T(T(v)) - T(v) = 0 then it follows no, since it is linear?